# Вывод данных из CMD

Tags: python

Каким образом можно получить данные из cmd, а в частности arp -a,

```
import os
a = os.popen('arp -a')
```

Необходимо вывести IP - MAC, желательно не потеряв исходного вида. Сам не знаю как выводить данные с консоли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
a = os.popen('arp -a')
result = a.read()
a.close()
print(result)
```

Через `subprocess` с нормальной кодировкой:

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output(['arp','-a'])
print(str(x, encoding='cp866'))
```

Comment: Выдает кракозябры, через subproccess не получается, функцию read не распознает.

Comment: @0x00 кракозябры тут из-за того, что CMD выдает текст в кодировке `cp866`, добавил новый вариант в пост, попробуйте его.